# Why is "requiretty" not working?

Tags: debian, ssh, sudo

It's my understanding that the `requiretty` option does not allow sudo on PTYs.

My VM's `sudoers`:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
Defaults        passwd_tries=3
Defaults        badpass_message="WRONG PASSWORD T_T"
Defaults        log_input, log_output, iolog_dir="/var/log/sudo"
Defaults        requiretty
# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d`
```

After connecting to this system with SSH, the `tty` program outputs `/dev/pts/0`.

But I can still sudo with a password in the SSH session. Does this `requiretty` option have nothing to do with SSH or PTYs? How can I sudo in my SSH session?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your understanding is not correct: a pseudo-TTY is considered fully equivalent to a "real" TTY.

When `tty` prints `/dev/pts/0` it means the session has a valid TTY.

But if you connect to the VM with SSH default settings and specify the command to run, the situation will be different:

```
$ ssh VM-user@VM-hostname "hostname; tty"
VM-hostname
not a tty
```

and *that* is the situation rejected by `sudo`'s `requiretty` option.

The requirement for a TTY allows SSH to reject attempts to pipe in the response to the password prompt via standard input, like many other Unix programs do when requesting a password.

It also allows you to do things like this:

```
sudo -u some-user data_producing_command 2> error-log-file | data_consuming_command
```

without the password prompt getting neither mixed in to the data piped to `data_consuming_command`, nor into the `error-log-file`. (Note that `data_consuming_command` here is run as yourself, not as `some-user`!)

In other words, with `requiretty` set, you cannot use `sudo` in contexts like:

- remote commands via SSH unless you force TTY allocation, i.e. `ssh VM-user@VM-host sudo something` would fail, but `ssh -tt VM-user@VM-host sudo something` would succeed.
- crontab commands, or scripts executed via crontab or `at` or `batch` commands
- scripts executed via `nohup`
- scripts executed via `cgi-bin` or any other daemonized process that has no relationship to user sessions

When `requiretty` is set and `sudo` is requesting a password, it does that in a way that is roughly similar in concept to this script snippet:

```
printf "[sudo] password for $USER: " > /dev/tty  # display prompt

TTYSETTINGS=$(stty -F /dev/tty --save)  # save current TTY settings
stty -F /dev/tty -echo -echoe           # prevent displaying the password

read PASSWORD < /dev/tty  

stty -F /dev/tty $TTYSETTINGS           # restore TTY settings 
# now check if $PASSWORD is correct...
```

`/dev/tty` is a "magic" device that will always act as an alias of the session's actual TTY device, if the session has a TTY. It exists precisely for things like this: to allow any script or program to "escape" piping or other input/output redirection and interact directly with the user when necessary.

If `requiretty` is set and `/dev/tty` is not usable (i.e. when the process has no real TTY associated with it), it is treated the same as a password authentication failure.

Comment: Thanks! It is a big help to me.  My understanding was wrong.